# Can you reassign a python object to an object at a different memory address?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, mpi

So I am currently trying to use the OpenMPI Python Library to create a parallel application to traverse a graph. I didn't get super far before I started to notice that the parallel processes weren't sharing the same object when communicating:

```
import pandas as pd
from collections import defaultdict
from mpi4py import MPI

comm = MPI.COMM_WORLD
rank = comm.Get_rank()

def add_edge(u,v,graph):
    graph[u].append(v)

if rank == 0:

    # A list to represent our graph
    graph = defaultdict(list)    
    # Read in data and build list of edges
    df = pd.read_csv('musae_facebook_edges.csv')
    data = df.head(100)
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        u = row['id_1'] 
        v = row['id_2']
        add_edge(u,v,graph)
else:
    graph = None

graph = comm.bcast(graph, root = 0)

if rank != 0:
    #graph = comm.recv(source=0, tag=11)
    print("{} has data of id: ".format(rank))
    print(id(graph))
    print(len(graph))
```

I noticed a problem that when I would try to write a new value to the graph it would not propagate to the other nodes. Running the above code via `mpiexec -np 3 python graphy-search.py` I get the following output:

```
1 has data of id: 
139922629199920
18357
2 has data of id: 
139664148236336
18357
```

Obviously, each process has its own copy of the graph somewhere in memory because the address of each graph object is different for each worker node and the root node. Again, when I try to update the graph during a search, the change does not reflect on the other nodes.

I think the easiest way to handle this problem would be to simply point the id of each processes' graph to the object that resides at the address specified by the root node's graph before we start the search, but I can't seem to find a way to do this. I understand that you inherently don't work with pointers in python, but does that mean there is no real way to solve this? If so, doesn't that seem like a huge limitation of python in regards to its applications in parallel programming?

I have tried with MPI's bcast, send/Recieve, etc but none of those seem to produce any different results. My only other option, I could see, would be to broadcast the change back to the root node every time one is made...but with the amount of data and number of Ops necessary for each process that doesn't really seem feasible.

Comment: MPI stands for Message Passing Interface. Long story short, each MPI tasks (aka process) has its own address space and send/receive message to other tasks. If you want a single memory space, you should be looking for other paradigms (e.g. multi-threading).

Comment: You are using multiprocessing, which inherently doesn't share state. Honestly, I don't do a lot of low-level programming, but usually it isn't trivial, and even in languages with low-level access to memory you can't simply pass a pointer between processes because they have a separate address space.